# Not able to insert the same record after connection interruption

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I was inserting some records in the production table ,while doing that before commit ,I lost the production connection and none of the record got inserted.

Now when I am trying to insert the same record ,the sql plus is getting hanged and data is not getting saved.

But when I tried for other record which I was not inserted ,those records are getting inserted.

I have checked the table again ,for availability of data.Those previous data has not stored anywhere.

SQL plus is not generating any error also ,so that I can check the error and try to rectify.

Can anyone please help me to analyse and troubleshoot the problem.

`while inserting in oracle the connection has lost now I am not able to add the same data`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SQL/Plus session hangs, it's probably being blocked by your previous session. To find the offending session, you can use (requires DBA privileges):

```
select * from v$lock where block = 1
```

This should give you the session ID of the blocking session. Now you can run

```
select * from v$session
```

and check whether the session ID returned by the first query indeed belongs to your previous session. To kill the session, use the command

```
alter system kill session '<SID>,<serial#>'
```

Comment: The second query is giving huge columns , I am not getting which coulmn to pick for serial#.can you please specify the column as well

Comment: Thanks Frank, but if I do not have admin privileges,then what I need to do?

Comment: @Suman - you will need to get your DBA, or someone else with the necessary privileges, to kill the session for you. If you accessed the database remotely it will probably time out eventually on its own, and if it's a local SQL*Plus session the operating system may end up killing it. You *might* also be able to send a hangup signal to your SQL*Plus process if it's local, but it isn't clear from your description.